Using a different background image for every LaTeX Beamer slide
I want to use a different background image for every LaTeX Beamer slide.  To do so I tried the following code:
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define a command to set a background image with an argument
\newcommand\SetBackground[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[at=(current page.center), anchor=center] {
                \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \SetBackground{background1.jpg}
    \frametitle{title 1}
    content 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \SetBackground{background2.jpg}
    \frametitle{title 2}
    content 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \SetBackground{background3.jpg}
    \frametitle{title 3}
    content 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}

If I compile this once with pdflatex background.tex I see the image not covering the whole background but shifted to upper right.  This shows that the is actually printed on top left but covered by the image when the image starts.  After the second invocation of pdflatex background.tex the image covers the whole background (as intended) but the title of the slides is hidden behind this.
What do I need to do to raise the layer of the title above the background image to show it on the final slide?
Kind regards, Andreas.

You can use the background canvas template for the image. This way it won't cover up the frame title:
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{image}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[image]{example-image-a}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title 1}
    content 1
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[image]{example-image-b}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title 2}
    content 2
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[image]{example-image-c}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title 3}
    content 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Perfect.  That's extremely helpful!  Thanks a lot.

@AndreasTille You're welcome!
